# Number of running clients in GWT Application?

Tags: java, gwt

I have a GWT client-server application and I want to display the number of running clients in the clients browser title. I know how to track the number of connecting clients but how can I track the number of closed connections?

```
public class MyServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServelt implements MyService
{
 [...]
 static int runningClients=0;
 @Override public Integer runningClients() {return ++runningClients;}
 // TODO: track closed connections
}
```

Edit: As suggested, I implemented an HTTPSessionListener. Unfortunately, it always returns 0 for both hits and connectedClients.

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionEvent;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener;

public class ActiveClientsListener implements HttpSessionListener
{   
    private static long hits = 0;
    private static long numberOfConnectedClients = 0;

    public static long hits() {return hits;}
    public static long numberOfConnectedClients() {return numberOfConnectedClients;}

    @Override public synchronized void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent arg0)
    {
        hits++;
        numberOfConnectedClients++;
    }

    @Override public synchronized void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent arg0)
    {
        numberOfConnectedClients--;
    }
}
```

**web.xml**

```
...
<listener>
 <listener-class>org.mypackage.server.ActiveClientsListener</listener-class>
</listener>
...
```

P.S.: Is my implementation threadsafe or do I have to make the fields `volatile` or synchronize differently?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that each connected client opens a session, I think I would use an [HttpSessionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/index.html?javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html) for that purpose.

When a session is created, you increase a counter, whenever it is destroyed, decrease it. Make sure that you synchronize the access to the variable.

Of course, the counter will decrease whenever the session times out which is probably "too late". However, you could probably improve this by explicitly destroying the session (session.[invalidate()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#invalidate%28%29)) when a user leaves your application (using [addWindowClosingHandler](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.4/com/google/gwt/user/client/Window.html#addWindowClosingHandler%28com.google.gwt.user.client.Window.ClosingHandler%29)).

Comment: Thanks, I will try this out right now! Don't mind waiting for the timeout, it doesn't have to be that exact.

Comment: I cannot call `getServlerContext().addListener()`: _The method addListener(String) is undefined for the type ServletContext_. The same error I get with a parameter of type `com.google.gwt.user.client.EventListener` and `java.util.EventListener`

Comment: Add the following in your deployment descriptor (web.xml): `<listener>
<listener-class>com.foo.bar.MySessionListener</listener-class>
</listener>` and make sure that this class implements `HttpSessionListener`

Comment: Unfortunately this always returns 0. Is it really enough to add it to the XML or do I have to add the listener somewhere in the program?

Comment: @kirdie did you put some logging in your class (constructor, sessionDestroyed, sessionCreated methods) to see what's going on? Yes, declaring it in the web.xml is enough. See also http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html and http://www.xyzws.com/Servletfaq/when-do-i-use-httpsessionlistener/7